# What is the relation between the version number in support library and SDK version?

Tags: android, android-support-library

First, I know about version system. 
Is there any relation between support library version and SD and minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?

ALso I want to know what does plus sign means in `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+`?

In fact I installed support library through SDK manager, but I don't know what should I exactly add to my dependencies? version 20, 21, 22, which one?

Answer (score 0):

first number is version, second is "sub-version", which may have some improvements, last one is changing in releases with bugfixes

thats why you are setting fixed first two numbers - another new version may behave different and mess up in your app, but oftenly you want latest "last number" with all bugfixes and that this plus mean (highest available number)

these are not stright-related to API, but new versions of libs are oftenly released with new version of API, so number is the same and smaller improvements/optimizations indicates second number

Comment: I know they are versions, but are they related to minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion? what is + sign? Which version I should use after installing support library?????????

Comment: + means "highest number", newest one. example: 22.2.+ might be 22.2.1 but when some fixes are implemented and version 22.2.2 is released then your sdk will automatically use this higher version (but if 22.3.x will be released your sdk will still be using newest 22.2.x)

Answer (score 0):

The three numbers are the version of the library that needs to be downloaded. If you use 22.2.+ gradle will automatically download the versions starting from
22.2.0 to 22.2.9 when they are available. I don't recommend this because this may change the behaviour of your app without your knowledge.

If you want to add the com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+ library in your project. 
Open the build.gradle file and add

> compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'

To the dependencies. Then click sync

Comment: Which version I should use after installing support library? I want to develop an app using material design and App Bar/ActionBar.

Comment: You should compile these files (just copy and paste them into your dependencies) compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.1' compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1' compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'

Answer (score 0):

There is general pattern that has three parts divided by colons. That pattern is

### **Id.of.library** : **ArtifactName**:**version.of.lib**

So in your example **appcompat-v7** is a name of artifact and **22.2.0** is a number of version.

Think you should always pick newest version of software you use. Good luck!